# Apollo-client crashes in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm using apollo for graphql. Everything works in Chrome no problem, but when I start my website in Internet explore I get this weird error.

Error

> fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for
>   your environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/unfetch.
>   For example:

```
import fetch from 'unfetch';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
const link = createHttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch: fetch });
```

So I tried their approach but I still get the same error.

Changed code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import fetch from 'unfetch';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';


 const link = createHttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch: fetch });


  const jsx = (
    <ApolloProvider client={link}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CookiesProvider>
              <AppRouter/>
            </CookiesProvider>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );

  ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Original:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';


  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "/graphql"
  });

  const jsx = (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CookiesProvider>
              <AppRouter/>
            </CookiesProvider>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );

  ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
```

So what i'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unless you have a serious business case for support of IE, just let IE die. Show a message for people to switch to edge. You're not trying to support Netscape Navigator either are you?

Comment: You are using it aa a _ponyfill_ which is not probably what Apollo client is expecting. Try with `import 'unfetch/polyfill'`. Also: be sure to make this import at the very beginning of you application (in the main index.js for example)

Comment: The place where i work main browser is IE, yeah i know... @tschallacka

Comment: My bundle.js now gets a syntax error, so it didn't work. @LucaFabbri

Comment: `import fetch from 'unfetch';` works for you while `import 'unfetch/polyfill'` gives a syntax error? Seems weird to me.

Comment: Last you can try: manually add unfetch to your HTML page adding `<script src="https://unpkg.com/unfetch/polyfill"></script>` before you bundle.